# Configure SQL linter casing depending on keyword

Tags: static-analysis, sqlfluff

Is it possible to configure SQLFluff to make some keywords upper case and other lower case?

- upper case: SELECT, FROM, JOIN
- lower case: as, on, case, when, else, end

The following snippet should be an example result.

```
SELECT
    a,
    case when b >= 42 then 1 else 0 end as c
FROM some_table as S
JOIN another_table as T
    on a is not null
        and b > 0
```